# ManicTime and Visual Studio 2012: Tracking documents/files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, time-management

I do most of my work is Visual Studio 2012. I also use ManicTime to help me get an idea of how much time I spend working on certain things. However, I'm having trouble getting these two programs to work in concert.

The core problem, I think, is that VS2012 does not show the currently opened file name in the title bar. It shows the solution name, but that isn't all that useful for me in my situation; I really need to know the specific file name that I'm working on at a given time. Because of this, ManicTime is not able to track the files I work on in the "Documents" section of what its tracking feature.

I was able to fix this in VS2010 with a macro I came across. It would update Visual Studio's title bar with the name of the file, and update it every time you switched to a different file. But in VS2012, the entire macro feature no longer exists, so I can't go that route.

I've given [VSCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/home) a shot, but I don't think it gets quite there. It shows the file name in the "badge" / Aero Peek preview, but it still doesn't update the title bar, and ManicTime still doesn't show any information about the files I work on in VS2012.

Can anyone come up with a way to make this work? Or some other process that doesn't involve ManicTime?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite dated: ManicTime added a Plugin Manager with version 3.1. This contains also a Visual Studio plugin (apart from many others) that tracks the file path in the Document timeline which should be exactly what you want.

The plugin should also exist in earlier versions, but I couldn't find out since when.